# Is it possible to combine static-value and cell-reference data points in a single Excel chart series?

Tags: excel, charts

I want to create a Combo chart in Excel, one part smooth scatter (really, just a smooth line) and the second part a stacked bar. So far, easy. But, I only have a single stacked bar, which I want to put at the bottom of the chart, rather than through the middle. This requires multiple zero-value elements in each of the series making up the stack.

While I can overload the series with lots of references to empty cells, I would rather just fill it with 0's - less risk of the referenced cell being used later.

Now, I can populate a data series by pointing to a cell, or range of cells. I can, also, populate it with static values, e.g. `={0,0,0}`. But I can't find a syntax to combine the two, allowing a string of zero-values and my one real data point per series.

Any suggestions?

[edit]
Per a comment request below, the visual representation of what I want to achive without having to reference stray cells.
[image: default v. stacked bar positioning]

Comment: Some sample data would go quite a long way here.

Comment: I would still advise to use cells and figure out a way to inform the user which should not be changed. Or you could simply protect the sheet after unlocking the cells which may be edited.